# Clicking multiple times on the thumbnail bugs the site out. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this problem with the first thumbnail (top left). When i click on it, it shows the list of tracks in the album (as it should), but when i click one more time, while it's showing the list, the list shows one more time overlaping the first list. I've tried everything, sites, turorials, etc, bit i can't seem to fix this bug. Please help.

PS.School project - please go easy:D

Site code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="pl">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Wu-Tang Dyskografia</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Google Fonts -->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Google Fonts -->

    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/style.css" />
    <!-- CSS -->

    <!-- JavaScript -->
    <script src="javascript/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="javascript/script.js"></script>
    <!-- JavaScript -->
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <header>
            <div class="logo">
                <img src="images/logo.jpg"/>
            </div>
        </header>
        <main>
            <div class="mainContainer">
            <article class="album">
                <div>
                    <img src="images/covers/cover1.jpg"/>
                    <span>Enter The Wu-Tang (36 chambers)</span>
                </div>
            </article>

            <article class="album">
                <div>
                    <img src="images/covers/cover2.jpg"/>
                    <span>Wu-Tang Forever</span>
                </div>
            </article>

            <article class="album">
                <div>
                    <img src="images/covers/cover3.jpg"/>
                    <span>The W</span>
                </div>
            </article>

            <article class="album">
                <div>
                    <img src="images/covers/cover4.jpg"/>
                    <span>Iron Flag</span>
                </div>
            </article>

            <article class="album">
                <div>
                    <img src="images/covers/cover5.jpg"/>
                    <span>8 Diagrams</span>
                </div>
            </article>

            <article class="album">
                <div>
                    <img src="images/covers/cover6.jpg"/>
                    <span>A Better Tomorrow</span>
                </div>
            </article>
        </div>
        </main>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}
body{
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: black;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}
.container{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
header{
    background-color:black;
    width:100%;
    height: 250px;
    text-align: center;
}
header .logo{
    width:100%;
    height: 250px;
}
header .logo img{
    text-align: center;
    margin-top:25px;
    width:250px;
    height:200px;
}
main{
    width:100%;
}
main .mainContainer{
    padding-top:50px;
    max-width:700px;
    height:700px;
    display:flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    margin:0 auto;
}
main .mainContainer article{
    width:200px;
    height: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    color:yellow;
}
main .mainContainer article img{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
}
.textDiv{
    color:yellow;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var $enterTheWuTang = [
        'Bring Da Ruckus',
        'Shame On A Nigga',
        'Clan In Da Front',
        'Wu-Tang: 7th Chamber',
        'Can It Be All So Simple',
        'Da Mystery of Chessboxin',
        'Wu-Tang Clan Aint Nuthing Ta F Wit',
        'C.R.E.A.M.',
        'Method Man',
        'Protect Ya Neck',
        'Tearz',
        'Wu-Tang: 7th Chamber - Part II',
        'Method Man (Skun Mix)',
        'Conclusion'
    ];

    $('.album:nth-child(1)').on('click', function(){
        $('.album:nth-child(1)').removeClass('album');
        $('.album').hide();
        $('.checked').fadeIn(2000);

        $('.mainContainer').append('<div class="textDiv"></div>');

        for(i=0;i<=$enterTheWuTang.length-1;i++){
            $('.textDiv').append('<div class="textAreaDiv">'+ (i+1) + '.' +$enterTheWuTang[i]+'</div>');
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: You are never clearing that .textDiv after you update it the first time. Also you are appending another textDiv each click, you aren't overwriting the content. So everytime you update it you are just appending the same data over and over again.

Comment: $('.mainContainer').html(''); before append

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, you are adding things in the wrong place. You need to be updating the html of the item, not appending over and over again.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    var $enterTheWuTang = [
        'Bring Da Ruckus',
        'Shame On A Nigga',
        'Clan In Da Front',
        'Wu-Tang: 7th Chamber',
        'Can It Be All So Simple',
        'Da Mystery of Chessboxin',
        'Wu-Tang Clan Aint Nuthing Ta F Wit',
        'C.R.E.A.M.',
        'Method Man',
        'Protect Ya Neck',
        'Tearz',
        'Wu-Tang: 7th Chamber - Part II',
        'Method Man (Skun Mix)',
        'Conclusion'
    ];
    
    //UPDATED HERE - ADD THE DIV ONCE AND DON'T KEEP ADDING IT
    $('.mainContainer').append('<div class="textDiv"></div>');
    $('.album:nth-child(1)').on('click', function(){
        $('.album:nth-child(1)').removeClass('album');
        $('.album').hide();
        $('.checked').fadeIn(2000);

        //UPDATED HERE - CREATE A SINGLE DIV ELEMENT TO APPEND TO
        var elemList = $('<div>', {
          class: 'textAreaDiv'
        });
        
        for(i=0;i<=$enterTheWuTang.length-1;i++){
        
        //UPDATED HERE - APPEND THE LIST ELEMENT TO YOUR DIV FROM ABOVE
            $(elemList).append('<div class="textAreaDiv">'+ (i+1) + '.' +$enterTheWuTang[i]+'</div>');
        }
        
        //UPDATED HERE - UPDATE THE HTML FOR THAT DIV.
        $('.textDiv').html(elemList);

    });
});
```

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}
body{
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: black;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}
.container{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
header{
    background-color:black;
    width:100%;
    height: 250px;
    text-align: center;
}
header .logo{
    width:100%;
    height: 250px;
}
header .logo img{
    text-align: center;
    margin-top:25px;
    width:250px;
    height:200px;
}
main{
    width:100%;
}
main .mainContainer{
    padding-top:50px;
    max-width:700px;
    height:700px;
    display:flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    margin:0 auto;
}
main .mainContainer article{
    width:200px;
    height: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    color:yellow;
}
main .mainContainer article img{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
}
.textDiv{
    color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="pl">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Wu-Tang Dyskografia</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Google Fonts -->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Google Fonts -->

    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/style.css" />
    <!-- CSS -->

    <!-- JavaScript -->
    <script src="javascript/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="javascript/script.js"></script>
    <!-- JavaScript -->
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <header>
            <div class="logo">
                <img src="images/logo.jpg"/>
            </div>
        </header>
        <main>
            <div class="mainContainer">
            <article class="album">
                <div>
                    <img src="images/covers/cover1.jpg"/>
                    <span>Enter The Wu-Tang (36 chambers)</span>
                </div>
            </article>

            <article class="album">
                <div>
                    <img src="images/covers/cover2.jpg"/>
                    <span>Wu-Tang Forever</span>
                </div>
            </article>

            <article class="album">
                <div>
                    <img src="images/covers/cover3.jpg"/>
                    <span>The W</span>
                </div>
            </article>

            <article class="album">
                <div>
                    <img src="images/covers/cover4.jpg"/>
                    <span>Iron Flag</span>
                </div>
            </article>

            <article class="album">
                <div>
                    <img src="images/covers/cover5.jpg"/>
                    <span>8 Diagrams</span>
                </div>
            </article>

            <article class="album">
                <div>
                    <img src="images/covers/cover6.jpg"/>
                    <span>A Better Tomorrow</span>
                </div>
            </article>
        </div>
        </main>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

So basically, I updated your click function to do 3 different things.

1. Add the div before you start appending things, this stops the elment from being added over and over again.
2. Create a new element that we will append to. This creates a clean element start from.
3. Add the element outside of the for-loop once to append it once and for all.

Comment: So i changed the js to what you gave and i works great! Thanks for you're time and help:D

Comment: No worries! Just make sure to understand the changes I listed, don't just copy paste ;)